Excel to dynamically generate SQL script using formula
I am trying to dynamically generate SQL INSERT scripts via Excel formulas
My Excel sheet looks as below.

Below is my formula
="INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROLE_ID,GROUP,SUBGROUP) values('"&D8&"','"&$E$8&"','"&$F$8&"')"

Now, I want the expected output to be generated as below;

So basically, for Column G, I want the generated script to use data from Columns D, E and F. However, the information of Column D would change as per the current row, Columns E and F would repeat till we get an empty row (or as we can use value '0' in Column D to identify that it should now use new values for GROUP and SUBGROUP)
="INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (MYROLE) values('"&E7&"');"
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (MYROLE) values(null);
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (MYROLE) values('My Role');
=IF(ISBLANK(E7), "INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (MYROLE) values(null);", "INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (MYROLE) values('"&E7&"');")
insert into MYSCHEMA.MY_DESTINATION_TABLE(COL_ID, COL2)
select 'USER1', COL2
from MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE where USER_ID = 'USER1';
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MY_DESTINATION_TABLE (COL_ID, COL2)
SELECT COL_ID, COL2
FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE COL_ID IN (SELECT COL_ID FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE);
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MY_DESTINATION_TABLE (COL_ID, DESTINATION_COL2)
SELECT COL_ID, SOURCE_COL2
FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE COL_ID IN (SELECT COL_ID FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE);
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MY_DESTINATION_TABLE (DEST_COL_ID, DEST_COL2)
SELECT
SOURCE_COL_ID,
CASE
WHEN SOURCE_COL1 = 'My Name 1' THEN 'MY_NAME_1'
WHEN SOURCE_COL1 = 'My Name 2' THEN 'MY_NAME_2'
-- Add more mappings as needed
ELSE SOURCE_COL1  -- Default case, if no match is found
END
FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE
WHERE SOURCE_COL_ID IN (SELECT SOURCE_COL_ID FROM MYSCHEMA.MY_SOURCE_TABLE);
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MYCONSTRRAINT FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_ID, R_ID) REFERENCES MY_ROLE (PERSON_ID, R_ID);
valueGetter: (params) => {
const someNumber = params.data?.someNumber || "";
const ext = params.data?.ext ?  Extn:${params.data.ext} : "";
return ${someNumber}${ext};
}
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
field.setAccessible(true);
}
"Not able to process request because of exception java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @27508c5d"
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.TABLE1 MODIFY COL1 VARCHAR2(50) NULL;
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA1.TABLE1 MODIFY COL2 VARCHAR2(8) NULL;
axiosPostCall(apiUrl, payload)
.then((response) => {
responseHandler(response)
.catch((e) => {
// console.log("Error");
errorHandler(e,setServerErr)
})
.finally(() => setLoading(false));
valueGetter: (params) => {
const fileName = params.data.someField1 || ""; // Ensure field is not undefined
return fileName.replace(/.[^/.]+$/, ""); // Remove the extension
},
PS I:\Code\myapp-report-ui> git status
On branch feature/version-20250117
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/version-20250117'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   src/components/MyComp.js
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
PS I:\Code\myapp-report-ui> git commit -m "JIRA-37434 : Map mesaage"
On branch feature/version-2011
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/version-2011'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   src/components/MyComp.js
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

XLS

doc
txt

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2, B:B, 0)), "", A2)

Did you try MAP() function? =MAP(D8:D16,E8:E16,F8:F16,LAMBDA(x,y,z,IF(x=0,"","INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROLE_ID,GROUP,SUBGROUP) values('"&z&"','"&y&"','"&z&"')"))).

You can use:
=IF(D8:D16=0,"","INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ROLE_ID,GROUP,SUBGROUP) values('"&D8:D16&"','"&E8:E16&"','"&F8:F16&"')")


